# Sequel gem update Clob field issue

Tags: ruby, sequel

I use Oracle database to store information about courses.
I have `Course` model

```
class Course < Sequel::Model
  set_dataset Sequel.lit(TABLE_NAME_HERE)
  set_primary_key :offer_rk
end
```

Each course has a description which can have more than 4000 length.
So I have been forced to set type of `description` column to `Clob`.

In my code I have something like

```
course.update description: large_text_here
```

Unfortunately it raises an error

```
OCIError: ORA-01704: string literal too long
```

Seems like Sequel saves description as ordinary `String` not as `Clob` value.

What should I do to save large text in `Clob` field correctly?

Should I patch this method somehow?

```
module Sequel
  module JDBC
    module Oracle
      module DatabaseMethods
        def schema_column_type(db_type)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the prepared_statements plugin:  `Course.plugin :prepared_statements`

Comment: Thank you, Jeremy. It solves the issue. Now I am stuck with `U+2019 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII` exception. But I think it is not Sequel problem.

Comment: I figured out this encoding problem. I should set `NLS_LANG` enviromnent. In case I set it to `AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8`.